# How can I update database with laravel at same view page?

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to get customer information from database with index. And at the same page, I wanted to update this information without creating edit page.But
whenever editing data and pressing button, I'm getting '419|Page Expired' error. Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance..

My index.blade.php is

```html
 <div class="widget-body clearfix">
     @foreach($posts as $post)
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('front.home.index') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">                         
        <div class="form-group row customerinfo--area">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label class="col-form-label" for="l0">Name</label>
          <input value="{{$post->customername}}" class="form-control" name="customername" type="text">
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label class="col-form-label" for="l0">Email</label>
          <input value="{{$post->email}}" class="form-control" name="email" type="text">
        </div>                                              
       <div class="form-actions">
          <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-12 ml-md-auto btn-list">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded" type="submit">Save</button>
          </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     </form>
     @endforeach
     </div>
```

My indexController is

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\front\home;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Customers;

class indexController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
 $posts=DB::select("select * from `customers` where id=1");
        return view('front.home.index',['posts'=>$posts]);
    }
    public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        $all = $request->except('_token');
        $data = Customers::where('id','1')->get();
        $update = Customers::where('id','1')->update($all);
        
 if($update)
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('status','Customer was edited');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('status','Customer was not edited');
        }
    }
 }
```

My web.php/routes is

```html
Route::group(['namespace'=>'front','prefix'=>'front','as'=>'front.'],function(){
   Route::group(['namespace'=>'home','as'=>'home.'],function(){
           Route::get('/','indexController@index')->name('index');
    Route::post('/','indexController@edit')->name('edit');
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you add the @csrf for the form. I cant see it in your code

Comment: Thank you @NipunTharuksha, I forgot csrf, my code can update:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Laravel form requires a csrf token, and you're missing it. Add it right below your form opening:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    @csrf
    ...
```

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf

Comment: Thank you @zlatangoralija :)

Comment: No problem. If this helped you, mark it as an answer.